# Publishing images of paintings

Tags: publishing

My wife and I are working on a book that will contain photographs of paintings that were exhibited, with owner permission, in shows hung by wife or obtained from other photographs. All of the works are by the same artist.  She is not doing the book for profit. It is purely a public service to help preserve and increase local knowledge concerning a local self-taught artist who died in 1982.  My wife has a record of the owners of all the works.  However, many of them are deceased.  If she publishes photos of the paintings in her book, with attribution to the last known owner, but does not have written permission to do so, what is her liability exposure?

Comment: Ask a lawyer. Seriously, don't ask anonymous folk on the web.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the copyright protection period has expired, those works are copyright and if you use them without permission, you could be sued. Copyrights are property and are part of the estate of a deceased person. The copyright holders are the heirs. Any publisher you approach is going to insist on your getting copyright releases for those works. Also note that the photograph of a painting is a copyrighted work in its own right, even if the original painting is out of copyright. IANAL, however. If you are concerned about liability, consult a qualified copyright lawyer.

Comment: I have spoken with the only known surviving heirs.  They have no objection to use of the photographs.  Do I still need permission from the current owners of the works?

Comment: Yes. You need written permission from the copyright holders.

Comment: @ASmith you would also need to make sure that the owners did not purchase reproduction rights when they bought the paintings.  (Probably they didn't, but you'd want the estate to verify that they did not sell them.)

Answer (score -3):

From a laymans standpoint, I really don't see a problem with it. Firstly, you aren't making any profit from it, so the owners of the pictures can't exactly be losing out on this deal can they? Secondly, lots of books use photographs from other authors. As long as they are properly attributed who is to argue? I see it the same as a quote really. You can quote another author freely as long as it is clearly a quote. So why shouldn't the same apply to pictures?

If you are seriously concerned, perhaps contacting a publisher would give you clarity on this? I know that's not much but I hope it helps.

Comment: This is completely wrong. A picture is intellectual property and copyright applies just as much as it does to writing. Whether you make a profit from violating someone else's copyright makes absolutely no difference, and the person who owns the copyright sill loses because they lose the opportunity to make that sale. You need a license of copyright from the copyright holder to use a copyrighted work. Fair use doctrine applies to certain limited cases for partial citations, but not for the whole work.

Comment: I did say from a laymans standpoint. Was it really nessesary to answer the question in your answer and then slam mine via comment? Do you think that was helpful? Or do you like putting people down and making them feel small?

Comment: I have spoken with only surviving heirs. They have no objection to our use of the photographs.  Do I still need permission from the current owner of the original work?

Comment: Nothing to do with slamming you. Simply about correcting misinformation that might be seen by others.

Comment: Could have softened the opening line a little, just FYI. Reads as a little harsh.

Comment: @WhiteS. Mark is criticising the information, not you personally.